# How to get properties of an application

Tags: applescript

I want to get the `properties` of an Application (the name is given as command-line argument). Basically I want to know if the `application_name` in command-line argument is front-most or not.

This is what I have been doing (It is working for me)

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    get properties
end tell
```

But when I try to do this:

```
on run argv
  tell application (item 1 of argv)
    get properties
  end tell
end run
```

I'm getting an error when executing it with command `osascript has_focus.scpt "Google Chrome"`

> environment/mac/scripts/has_focus.scpt:56:66: execution error: Google
> Chrome got an error: Can’t get every property. (-1728)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work.

The argument of `tell application` must be a (literal) constant because the terminology is evaluated at compile time.

An exception are the properties `version`, `frontmost` and `running` which any application retrieves. These properties are internally organized as Application Object and independent of an existing AppleScript dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure? I have some other code that takes `app_name` as argument and checks whether it is running or not, and it works fine.
See this: https://pastebin.com/wEL4X98w

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. There are a couple of commands **any** application responds to – even if it does not have an explicit AppleScript dictionary –  for example `isRunning`, `version` and `frontmost`. For those commands resolving terminology is not necessary.

Comment: You are a genius. I just wanted to know if my app is frontmost or not. And didn't knew I can use `frontmost`. Thanks a lot, sir.

Comment: If possible can you add your last statement in the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I see that you solved your problem through the discussion, and learned about the `frontmost` property for `application` objects.

So this is more of a point of interest to complete what you originally started.

@vadian was correct by stating:

> *The argument of tell application must be a (literal) constant because the **terminology is evaluated at compile time**.*

The solution around this is to not utilise terminology.  Terminology requires that the application being instructed be able to lookup the terminologies used in its scripting dictionary, and convert them from human-friendly terms to raw Apple event codes.  So take away the middle man, and you can issue statements, give commands, and retrieve properties by way of raw chevron syntax:

```
on run argv
    set [appName] to argv
    tell the application named appName ¬
            to return its «class pALL»
end run
```

Then, in a terminal:

```sh
osascript ~/Scripts/getAppProperties.applescript "Brave Browser"

«class ChBB»:«class CrBF» id 1, frontmost:false, «class ChOB»:«class CrBF» id 2,
class:application, name:Brave Browser, version:83.1.10.97
```

Naturally, with no dictionary lookup, the application-specific properties and their values are returned in raw syntax.

---

**Note:** Entering raw syntax codes into *Script Editor* can be a bit tricky, as it will immediately compile and any terms that are understood either by *Script Editor* or AppleScript (such as `properties`, which features commonly across the board and with the same type code).  But you can create an AppleScript in any plain text editor.  If you really must compile it into a `.scpt` file, then `osacompile` will do that.